# Converting TFRS to the tflite model

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, recommendation-engine

I am new to Tensorflow and I need to convert the TFRS to the tflite model. Does anyone have any idea or experience related to this topic?

I simply ran the retrieval code by Colab.
And added the recommended method to convert the final model to tflite. That was:

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(path) # path to the SavedModel directory
tflite_model = converter.convert()

You can see the error in the following image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wDfc.png)

Comment: Hi! Can you please provide a sample stand alone  code as Colab gist to expedite the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the latest [tf-nightly](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly/) pip and then convert this model using new MLIR converter. You can enable the new converter by setting:

```
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
```